Faild Test Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
Test failed with exception
    Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 Could not initialize class io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType"

I have dependencies for posgres + jpa + jsonb.
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55:3.7.0")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")

entity
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinition
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table(name = "route")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
class RouteEntity(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: String,

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", name = "event_data", nullable = false)
    var eventData: RouteDefinition
)

When I run app without test, app run correctly.
But when I build with 'test', I have:
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:

script gradle
ver gradle-7.5.1-bin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.7"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.7.20"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.21"
    java
    id("idea")
    id("io.sentry.jvm.gradle") version "4.2.0"
    jacoco
}

version = ""
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val testcontainersVersion = "1.17.6"
extra["testcontainersVersion"] = "1.17.6"
extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2021.0.5"

dependencies {

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.21")
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api")
    implementation("io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("io.prometheus:simpleclient_pushgateway:0.15.0")

    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.24.Final")
    implementation("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.5.9.Final")
    implementation("org.javassist:javassist:3.30.2-GA")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    implementation("io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55:3.7.0")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.0")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.19.0")

    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.1.5")

    implementation(
        group = "io.opentracing.contrib",
        name = "opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter",
        version = "3.3.1"
    )
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-hppc")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j")
    implementation("org.springframework.retry:spring-retry")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging")
    implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.11")
    implementation("org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.9")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.zalando:problem-spring-webflux:0.28.0-RC.0")

    implementation("com.playtika.reactivefeign:feign-reactor-spring-cloud-starter:3.2.6")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")

    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    implementation("io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static")

    // OPEN API
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.12")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui:1.6.12")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.6.12")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.4")
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:4.0.2")
    testImplementation("org.awaitility:awaitility-kotlin:4.2.0")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:$testcontainersVersion")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:$testcontainersVersion")
    testImplementation("com.github.dasniko:testcontainers-keycloak:3.2.0")
    annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:2.7.5")

    // other
    implementation("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.9.3")
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:4.2.1")

    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.18")
    implementation("io.netty:netty-bom:4.1.85.Final")
    // macos m1 dns resolver
    implementation("io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:4.1.87.Final:osx-aarch_64")

    // grpc
    implementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.4.24")
    implementation("io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter:7.3.0")

    // mocking web
    testImplementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.10.0")

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

This is almost the entire gradle file. I removed part of it to pass site validation. otherwise the file is very large.

What version of spring boot are you using ?

"2.7.7" version

I guess now that you are mixing version in your project. Could you please share the whole build.gradle file ?

I added gradle file
